# How many pitches does a reliever usually need to warm up?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

A one-inning "reliever" in Major League Baseball will typically throw between 5 and 20 pitches in a game. How many warm up pitches does he need before he can do this?

Said reliever is allowed up to eight "practice" pitches from the mound (except in the case of an unexpected injury, when the reliever gets as many pitches as he needs). So how many pitches might the reliever have thrown in the bullpen before being called into a game?

Comment: This depends a lot of things ranging from team protocol to the game situation to the individual pitcher. I don't really think a good specific answer can be given but I would say that a pitcher would throw an average of 20-30 pitches in the bullpen starting with soft warm up tosses and ending with full speed hard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the individual pitcher. You are granted 8 pitches when brought in during an inning but while in the bullpen, you basically throw until you're ready and only you know that.